Teams Message POST fails with Graph-API App type token
First of all, I think the type of authentication being used is the application.

Create an app and set permissions
I created an app with Microsoft Entra and set the Permissions as shown in the image below.



Obtaining an Access Token
o   We got an access token in the following two steps.
Admin Consent URL
Token URL
o   Parameter:
   grant_type:client_credentials

Then, when I tried to send a message to a channel using the above app, I ran into the following two issues:
Issue 1: Error sending message
I tried to send a message using the Microsoft Graph API to a channel for an existing team that I created in Teams, but I got the following error:
Error message:
**MessageWritesBlocked-Thread is not markedfor import
**
Failed requests:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{ID}/channels/{ID}/messages

"error": {
"code": "Forbidden",
"message": "InsufficientPrivileges",
"innerError": {
"code": "1",
"message": "MessageWritesBlocked-Thread is not marked for import",
"date": "2024-08-05T22:48:34",
"request-id": "9*********************b",
"client-request-id": "**********************b"

Send message to Teams using Graph-API POST.
Error : "message": "MessageWritesBlocked-Thread is not marked for import",

try add application self-permission ChannelMessage.Send


Note that: Application permissions support only for migration Refer this MsDoc


Hence either you can make use of delegated permissions and delegated flow to send message in channel.
Otherwise, create a migration team and channel to use application permissions and client credential flow.

Created a Microsoft Entra ID application and granted API permissions like below:

Generated access token via Client credential flow:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:client_credentials
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
client_id:ClientID


To make application permissions work, create a team in migration state:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "@microsoft.graph.teamCreationMode": "migration",
  "template@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')",
  "displayName": "My Sample Team",
  "description": "My Sample Team’s Description",
  "createdDateTime": "2024-08-06T11:22:17.043Z"
}`


Now, create a channel in migration state:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team-id}/channels
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "@microsoft.graph.channelCreationMode": "migration",
  "displayName": "Architecture Discussion",
  "description": "This channel is where we debate all future architecture plans",
  "membershipType": "standard",
  "createdDateTime": "2024-08-06T11:22:17.047Z"
}


I am able to send message successfully using application permissions:

Otherwise, if you don't want migration then grant delegated API permissions and use delegated flow:

Generated access token via Authorization code flow:

Grant type: Authorization code 

Callback URL: https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback
Auth URL:  https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
Token URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
Client ID : ClientID
Client Secret : ClientSecret
Scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default


Now I am able to send message to channel successfully without migration:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/TeamsID/channels/ChannelID/messages
Content-type: application/json

{
  "body": {
    "content": "Hello World"
  }
}


Reference:
microsoft teams - Graph API error message: "Message POST is allowed in application-only context only for import purposes" - Stack Overflow by Prasad-MSFT
